# Problems with serialization in java, calling a stateless javabean from a primefaces baking bean

Tags: java, serialization, primefaces, javabeans

First of all: sorry for my english, I'll try to do my best :)

I have a Java EE application, with javabeans providing the logic via remote interfaces and a primefaces interface with his baking beans. For example I have this in my ejb project:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class reporteService implements reporteServiceRemote {
    [...]
    public LinkedList<LineaBalanceteSaldosClientesTransport> balanceteSaldosClientes(...parameters...) {
        LinkedList<LineaBalanceteSaldosClientesTransport> lineas = new LinkedList<>();
        // execute a native query and return the results
        // the query return about 6/700 rows
        List results = this.balanceteSaldosClientes(...parameters...);
        Iterator it = results.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Object[] result = (Object[])it.next();
            String codigoCliente        = (String) result[0];
            Integer idCliente           = (Integer) result[1];
            Integer nombreCliente       = (String) result[2];
            // generate new line
            linea = new LineaBalanceteSaldosClientesTransport();
            linea.setIdCliente(idCliente);
            linea.setCodigoCliente(codigoCliente);
            linea.setNombreCliente(nombreCliente);
            lineas.add(linea);
        }
        return lineas;
    }
    [...]
}

@Remote
public interface ReporteServiceRemote {
    [...]
    public LinkedList<LineaBalanceteSaldosClientesTransport> balanceteSaldosClientes(...parameters...);
    [...]
}
```

This works fine, I've tried outputting the lines and the final linkedlist in the log and the method ends fine. The point is calling the method from the war, using his remote interface. This is the baking bean for a primefaces page that is supposed to show the results:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ReporteBean implements Serializable {
    [...]
    @EJB
    private ReporteServicesRemote reporteServices;
    [...]

    public LinkedList<LineaBalanceteSaldosClientesTransport> obtenerBalanceteSaldosClientes() {
        try {
            LinkedList<LineaBalanceteSaldosClientesTransport> lbsct = reporteServices.balanceteSaldosClientes(
                            this.getFechaSaldo(),
                            this.getIdsMonedas(),
                            cliente != null ? cliente.idCliente : null
            );
            return lbsct;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "ERROR", ex);            
            this.messagesBean.message(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "ERROR", "Error al intentar generar Balancete de Saldos: " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    [...]
}
```

when it call the method reporteServices.balanceteSaldosClientes it ends fine, but (I think) the serialization of the resulting object fail, throwing this exception:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: java.rmi.ServerError: Error occurred in server thread; nested exception is:
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.glassfish.pfl.dynamic.copyobject.impl.Exceptions
    at com.myproject.services.reportes._ReporteServicesRemote_Wrapper.balanceteSaldosClientes(com/myproject/services/reportes/_ReporteServicesRemote_Wrapper.java)
    at com.tecytal.utils.servlets.testServlet.processRequest(testServlet.java:124)
    at com.tecytal.utils.servlets.testServlet.doGet(testServlet.java:158)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.rmi.ServerError: Error occurred in server thread; nested exception is:
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.glassfish.pfl.dynamic.copyobject.impl.Exceptions
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.wrapException(Util.java:699)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:257)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:150)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:226)
    at com.myproject.services.reportes.__ReporteServicesRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.balanceteSaldosClientes(com/myproject/services/reportes/__ReporteServicesRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.java)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.glassfish.pfl.dynamic.copyobject.impl.Exceptions
    at org.glassfish.pfl.dynamic.copyobject.impl.ClassCopierBase.copy(ClassCopierBase.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.pfl.dynamic.copyobject.impl.ClassCopierOrdinaryImpl$ClassFieldCopierUnsafeImpl$17.copy(ClassCopierOrdinaryImpl.java:810)
    at org.glassfish.pfl.dynamic.copyobject.impl.ClassCopierOrdinaryImpl$ClassFieldCopierUnsafeImpl.copy(ClassCopierOrdinaryImpl.java:1008)
    at org.glassfish.pfl.dynamic.copyobject.impl.ClassCopierOrdinaryImpl.doCopy(ClassCopierOrdinaryImpl.java:1128)
    at org.glassfish.pfl.dynamic.copyobject.impl.ClassCopierBase.copy(ClassCopierBase.java:129)
    at org.glassfish.pfl.dynamic.copyobject.impl.ClassCopierOrdinaryImpl$ClassFieldCopierUnsafeImpl$17.copy(ClassCopierOrdinaryImpl.java:810)
    at org.glassfish.pfl.dynamic.copyobject.impl.ClassCopierOrdinaryImpl$ClassFieldCopierUnsafeImpl.copy(ClassCopierOrdinaryImpl.java:1008)
    at org.glassfish.pfl.dynamic.copyobject.impl.ClassCopierOrdinaryImpl.doCopy(ClassCopierOrdinaryImpl.java:1128)
    at org.glassfish.pfl.dynamic.copyobject.impl.ClassCopierBase.copy(ClassCopierBase.java:129)
    [...]
    (lot of similar lines repeated)
```

Someone pointed me to a memory problem, but in this case java was running with 8GB of dedicated memory (Xmx8192m, Xms8192m, MaxPermSize=4096m) and the linkedlist in this case contains only 600/700 objects. If I put i.e. a LIMIT 100 in the native query that returns the first list of results I get no exception and all works flawlessy.

I'm doing it wrong? Is there a more efficient way to pass datas between beans? Or there's another bug I cannot see?

Thank you for every suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be resolved using the Value List Handler pattern, more informations and working examples can be found here

- Core J2EE Patterns - Value List Handler - 
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/valuelisthandler-142464.html
- EJB 3.0 Stateful Session Bean Example -
  http://www.go4expert.com/articles/ejb-30-stateful-session-bean-example-t4212/

Hope this can help someone.